# simple login program in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have written a program in python for login without any GUI.
I know it is the simplest one but i don't understand the problem.

```
class login:
    def __init__(self,id,pas):
        self.id="admin"
        self.pas="admin"

    def check(id,pas):
        print self.id
        print lod.id
        if(self.id==log.id and self.pas==log.pas):
            print "Login success!"


log=login("","")
log.check(raw_input("Enter Login ID:"),
        input("Enter password: "))

print "Login Page"
```

Error:
    Enter Login ID:admin
    Enter password: admin

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/login.py", line 15, in <module>
    input("Enter password: "))
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'admin' is not defined
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You used `input()` instead of `raw_input()` for the password.

`input()` is the equivalent of `eval(raw_input())`; if you typed in `admin` for the password it is interpreted as Python code. `admin` is then interpreted as a variable name, and because that name doesn't exist in your code, a `NameError` is raised.

Use:

```
log.check(raw_input("Enter Login ID:"),
          raw_input("Enter password: "))
```

instead.

Next up, your `check()` method won't work, as you forgot the `self` parameter and are trying to reference a name `lod` that doesn't exist. The following would work better:

```
class login:
    def __init__(self, id, pas):
        self.id = id
        self.pas = pas

    def check(self, id, pas):
        print self.id
        if self.id == id and self.pas == pas:
            print "Login success!"

log = login("admin", "admin")
log.check(raw_input("Enter Login ID:"),
          raw_input("Enter password: "))
```

Comment: Martijn, that is only one part. The class definition is a mess.

Comment: @Matthias: first things first. :-)

Comment: You're right. That was the reason for the NameError. Let's wait and look what happens now.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I have one question.. If i want asterisk while taking password instead of plain text, How can it be done. Also how i compare it.

Comment: @user3201916: use the [`getpass.getpass()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/getpass.html) instead of `raw_input()` to take passwords. It won't print asterisks in that case, but the password will be hidden.

Comment: hint: for compatibility code in python 2.7+ put this into the beginning of the module: from __future__ import print_function But better use print() as a function. For python 3+ replace raw_input with input

Comment: @AdiCumpanasu: sure, but this question is about Python 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
class Login:
    def __init__(self, id, password):
        self.id = id
        self.password = password
        self.error = "Enter a valid username and password"
    def check(self):
        if (self.id == log_id and self.password == log_pass):
            print("Login successful")
        else:
            print(self.error)

log = Login("admin",  "admin")
log_id = input("Enter your user ID: ")
log_pass = input("Enter password: ")
log.check()
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! To post  code, please prepend each line with four spaces. Also, it would be nice if you gave some explanation to your code. Answers that are only a piece of code are usually not very well received around here.

Comment: class Login:
    error = None
    def __init__(self, uid, passw):
        self.uid = "admin"
        self.passw = "admin"
        Login.error = "Enter a valid user id and password"

    def authenticate(self):
        if (self.uid == logid and self.passw == logpass):
            print ("Login successful")
        else:
            print (Login.error)
log = Login("", "")
logid = input("Enter your user ID: ")
logpass = input("Enter your password: ")


log.authenticate()

Comment: class Login:
         error = None
         def __init__(self, uid, passw):
                self.uid = "admin"
                self.passw = "admin"
         Login.error = "Enter a valid user id and password"

         def authenticate(self):
                if (self.uid == logid and self.passw == logpass):
                       print ("Login successful")
                else:
                       print (Login.error)
             log = Login("", "")
         logid = input("Enter your user ID: ")
      logpass = input("Enter your password: ")


log.authenticate()

Answer (score 0):

Alright, there was no need for me to add id and pas argument to the check function since I already have it in the main function. I rather called self method and the "if" for authentication

```
class Login:
    error = None
    def __init__(self, uid, passw):
        self.uid = "admin"
        self.passw = "admin"
        Login.error = "Enter a valid user id and password"

    def authenticate(self):
        if (self.uid == logid and self.passw == logpass):
            print ("Login successful")
        else:
            print (Login.error)
log = Login("", "")
logid = input("Enter your user ID: ")
logpass = input("Enter your password: ")


log.authenticate()
```

Comment: In future, to format your code you can highlight all of it and press the format code button in the editor, it looks like this: `{}`